# C# add string without spaces into array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have got:

```
string pattern = "ABCDEFGH!";
```

and i want to get it into array (pattern can be longer or shorter):

```
array[0] = A
array[1] = B
array[2] = C
//etc.
```

I have tried something like this:

```
help = "ABCDEFGH!"
string[] pattern = help.Split("");
```

First i wanted to add space between all signs and than split and add them to my array but maybe there is better idea.

Comment: Do you NEED an array of strings, or can it be an array of `char` ? In the second case : `"ABCDEFGH!".ToArray()`

Comment: just do `"ABCDEFGH".ToCharArray()`, it splits your string into a array

Comment: it can be an array of chars

Comment: .ToCharArray() and .ToArray() works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following code will create an array of chars:

```
string pattern = "ABCDEFGH!";
char[] patternArray = pattern.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: It should be noted that, as mentioned in the documentation, a string is a sequential collection of characters that's used to represent text.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an array of string you could try something likee this, but maybe there's a better way to do it.

```
string help = "ABCDEFGH!";
string[] patern = new string[help.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < help.Length; i++)
{
    patern[i] = help[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that C# allows use of the index operator on strings to get characters from the string as if it were a char array. If you only need to access, simply do that

```cs
string pattern = "ABCDEFGH!";
Console.WriteLine(pattern[0]); //prints "A"
Console.WriteLine(pattern[1]); //prints "B"
//...

//can use slice/range operators also
Console.WriteLine(pattern[0..2]); //prints "ABC"
Console.WriteLine(pattern[^1]); //prints "!" [^1] == [pattern.Length - 1]
```

If you need to save to a variable, use `.ToCharArray()` and you also access by index

```cs
char[] pattern = "ABCDEFGH!".ToCharArray();
```

Of course, in either case watch out for IndexOutOfBounds

Answer (score 0):

Can be got both array(char or string) by Linq easily also

```
        string help = "ABCDEFGH!";
        var chararray = help.Select(x => x).ToArray();
        var stringarray = help.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        
        Console.WriteLine(chararray.GetType());
        
        Console.WriteLine(stringarray.GetType());
        
        foreach( var c in stringarray)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
```

OutPut

[image]